# regular expression character followed by number php

Tags: php, regex

I want to add backslashes to following string where `u` followed by number `0-9` with regular expression in PHP.

```
$string="u00fehehu2122k ru00f0ru00f0u00c4 ytu201ekuu2122e";
```

i want this result after converted.

```
$result="\u00feheh\u2122k r\u00f0r\u00f0\u00c4 yt\u201eku\u2122e";
```

i have write,

```
$string= preg_replace("/.u/", "\", $string);
```

but is does allow me to add `"\"` in second parameter.
so is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using capturing group to capture digit part.

```
$string = preg_replace('/u(\d)/', "\\u$1", $string);
```